# Why am I getting a "Syntax error in UPDATE statement." exception?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007, oledb

```
 public void EditUser(string id, string userid, string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            _dbConn.Open();

            OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE LOGINS SET Username=?, Password=?, Email=? WHERE ID=?", _dbConn);


            OleDbParameter param1 = new OleDbParameter("Username", userid);
            OleDbParameter param2 = new OleDbParameter("Password", password);
            OleDbParameter param3 = new OleDbParameter("Email", email);
            OleDbParameter param4 = new OleDbParameter("ID", id);

            param1.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param2.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
            param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param3.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
            param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param4.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
            param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(param3);
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(param4);


            int rowsAffected = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(excep.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                _dbConn.Close();

        }
        return;
    }
```

I'm using C# and Access 2007, this works perfectly fine when I'm updating a single column. But when I'm trying to update multiple columns at the same time I start to get this exception

> "Syntax error in UPDATE statement.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Password` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) in OLE DB Provider. You need to use it with square brackets like `[Password]`.

As a best practice, change it to *non-reserved* word.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbConnection` even we can't see it.

Comment: Thank you, also appreciate the advice on the `using` statement

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sonar. Password is a reserved keyword in OLE DB Provider.

If you are using multiple tables, To avoid Confusion from reserved keywords --
you must use. 
select table.[Password] from table;

*UPDATE table SET table.[Password]=?*